# Celluloid Scatter Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, plot

I have this function that will make an animated video of scatter plots. Although, the videos are not correct and do not correspond to the plots that should be getting snapped. Instead of capturing all the plots, it seems that the video is only the last plot.

```
def plotting(df,food,N):
    
    # intialize camera to be fixed on plot
    camera = Camera(plt.figure())

    for i in range(0,len(df['t'])):
        _x = df['x'][i]
        _y = df['y'][i]
        2_x = food['x'][i]
        2_y = food['y'][i]

        # plt.axis('off')
        plt.scatter(2_x,2_y,color='green',marker = '*') # food
        plt.scatter(_x[0],_y[0],color='red',marker = 'v') # leader x,y
        plt.scatter(_x[1:],_y[1:],color='blue',marker='v') # remaining x,y

        camera.snap()
        # plt.show()
    anim = camera.animate(blit=True) #,interval=300)
    file_name = '../docs/' + str(N) + 'test.mp4'
    anim.save(file_name)
```

When i do plt.show() the plots are right and the animated video is 10 seconds which is fine, but the video is the same frame for the whole time.

Comment: Please show an MCVE

Comment: What's `Camera`, and why aren't you using matplotlib's animation if you want to animate plots? You would have an answer by now if you had posted an [mcve].